# How to add an attribute or change style of a button onPress react native - native base

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, expo, native-base

I have a list with some items that are added to a state on click, Im using native-base, how can I change the style of the listitem when I press it, or add the "selected" attribute to the list item?

code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        button={true}
        onPress={() => handleItemSelect(item)}
      >
        <Left>
          <Text>{item.Name}</Text>
        </Left>
        <Right>
          <Icon name="add" style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5 }} />
        </Right>
      </ListItem>
    );
  };

return(
 <Container>
      <List>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={_renderItem}
        />
      </List>
    </Container>
);
```

Im wondering how am I going to add a style and distinguish between the different list items that I have, if this isn't possible how can I use native-base "selected" and append it to the listitem?

the handleItemSelect adds the item id to a state so im currently managing which items are selected, how can I use this info, or any other way to highlight the selected items?

---

Edit:
I figured how to easily do this since I have the selected items id's

```
 <ListItem
        selected={selectedItems.some((prevItem) => prevItem._id === item._id)}
        style={sameasabove ? style1 : style2}
        button={true}
        onPress={() => handleItemSelect(item)}
      >
      </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like this:

**Example**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { name: "Interstellar" },
        { name: "Dark Knight" },
        { name: "Pop" },
        { name: "Pulp Fiction" },
        { name: "Burning Train" },
      ],
      setData: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
      this.state.setData[i] = "red";
    }

    this.setState({
      setData: this.state.setData
    })
  }

  handleItemSelect(item, index) {
    this.state.setData[index] = "green";
    this.setState({
      setData: this.state.setData
    })
  }

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <ListItem button={true}
        onPress={() => this.handleItemSelect(item, index)} style={{ marginLeft: 0 }}>
        <Body>
          <Text style={{ color: this.state.setData[index] }}>{item.name}</Text>
        </Body>
      </ListItem>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

You can set a color to your ListItem initially and then you can change the color on a click event.

Hope this helps!